# Find all the indexes of a number in a list

Tags: python, python-3.3

I have the following list:

```
lista = [1,2,3,5,0,5,6,0]
```

I know that `print(lista.index(0))` will print the first index where it found the number i.e. 4

How do I get it to print the next index which should be 7 etc?

Answer (score 3):

The classic way is to build a list of the indices:

eg:

```
>>> indices = [i for i, v in enumerate(a) if v == 0]
>>> print indices
[4, 7]
```

Of course - this can be turned into a generator expression instead. But in short - using `enumerate` is what you're after.

Comment: How do I then delete the elements in lista from the indices?